# Alternative to Sapply in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to know how we can write similar to sapply in dplyr. Here I am calculating no. of distinct values. I have similar multiple sapply statements so I thought to write using `mutate` in dplyr.

```
distinctValues <- sapply(iris, function(var) dplyr::n_distinct(var))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Update:
for different names you can use `.names = "{.col}.new{.fn}"`

```
iris %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), n_distinct, .names = "{.col}.new{.fn}"))
```

We can use `summarize` with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  summarize(across(everything(), n_distinct))
```

Output:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1           35          23           43          22       3
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way we can label them differently?

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the following solution:

```
library(purrr)

iris %>%
  map_dbl(~ n_distinct(.x))

Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
          35           23           43           22            3
```

Answer (score 3):

In `base R`, we can do

```
sapply(iris, function(var) length(unique(var)))
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option using `uniqueN`

```
> as.data.table(iris)[, sapply(.SD, uniqueN)]
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width      Species 
          35           23           43           22            3
```

Comment: `sapply(iris, uniqueN)` is simpler and does the same.